# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionServiceFactory.createDefaultConversionService()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Can you please help in letting me know why this error is being returned in my spring boot application?

EDIT:

I am using DataRepostory class which extends CRUDRepository to perform crud operations in couchbase db

```
2015-08-29T02:36:24.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'couchbaseTemplate' while setting bean property 'couchbaseOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'couchbaseTemplate' defined in com.couch.CBConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate]: Factory method 'couchbaseTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingCouchbaseConverter' defined in com.couch.CBConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter]: Factory method 'mappingCouchbaseConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionServiceFactory.createDefaultConversionService()Lorg/springframework/core/convert/support/GenericConversionService;
2015-08-29T02:36:24.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
2015-08-29T02:36:24.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
2015-08-29T02:36:24.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
2015-08-29T02:36:24.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
2015-08-29T02:36:24.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1145)
2015-08-29T02:36:24.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
2015-08-29T02:36:24.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
2015-08-29T02:36:24.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
2015-08-29T02:36:24.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
2015-08-29T02:36:24.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1069)
```

Dependencies

```
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.1.RELEASE"
'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.CR2'
'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.1'
'com.couchbase.client:couchbase-client:1.4.7'
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator
"org.springframework.data:spring-data-couchbase:1.2.1.RELEASE"
"org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-test:4.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.data:spring-data-couchbase:1.3.0.RELEASE
group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web',version: '1.2.2.RELEASE'
group: 'com.mangofactory', name: 'swagger-springmvc', version: '0.8.8'
group: 'org.ajar', name: 'swagger-spring-mvc-ui', version: '0.1'
```

Comment: Could you post the stack trace and some info about your configuration ?

Comment: Hi ollie , I have added additional info.

Comment: Could you indicate version about project dependancies like spring boot, spring data, ... ?

Comment: Sure , I will update them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring 3.2 lists this method as deprecated [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/core/convert/support/ConversionServiceFactory.html); I suspect what has happened is that you have compiled against a version that still had this method, but are attempting to run it in an environment in which the deprecated method has been removed.  The one without the method would be more current.  Check the versions of libraries in both places, and ensure that you only have one such library in each place.

Comment: Thanks a lot , arcy. I will check.

Comment: That's the point. The problem come with the library : group: 'com.mangofactory', name: 'swagger-springmvc', version: '0.8.8' which depends on the spring version 3.2.7.RELEASE.

Comment: awesome , thanks ollie. I will check what 1.0.2 version of this lib depends on.

Comment: can I use the same version and exclude the spring dependency? It looks like even the latest version of this lib depends on Spring 3.2.9

Comment: Yes, you can with an exclusion rule (gradle, maven, ivy, ...).